# How to use glob file specifications for stylus on the command line?

Tags: command-line, npm, glob, stylus, package.json

I have many directories. In many of those there is a `.styl` file. I want to create a `.css` file within that same directory for each directory containing a `.styl` file. Additionally, whenever the `.styl` file is updated, I'd like the respective `.css` file to update.

I'm trying to create a script in my `package.json` to accomplish this, but without much luck. I don't know how to specify an output filename dynamically either, so I realize that part of the code bellow is incorrect. Before tackling that (potentially) I have an error I'll describe after the code. I'm open to an alternative output, **I just want my `.styl` files to stay in their modules and whatever `.css` file(s) that are output to update automatically**.

Here's the relevant commands from the `"scripts"` part of my `package.json`:

```
"styles": "stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus ./src/**/*.styl -o ./src/css/",
"styles:watch": "stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus -w ./src/**/*.styl -o ./src/css/",
"watch": "concurrently --names 'webpack, stylus' --prefix name 'npm run start' 'npm run styles:watch'"
```

Here's the error:

```
[ stylus] > stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus -w ./src/**/*.styl -o ./src/css/
[ stylus]
[ stylus] /Users/itsme/Projects/todo-react/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:641
[ stylus]     if (err) throw err;
[ stylus]              ^
[ stylus]
[ stylus] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat './src/**/*.styl'
```

Full `package.json` if it's helpful:

```
{
  "name": "todo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-stylus": "^0.13.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.8.5",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "styles": "stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus ./src/**/*.styl -o ./src/css/",
    "styles:watch": "stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus -w ./src/**/*.styl -o ./src/css/",
    "watch": "concurrently --names 'webpack, stylus' --prefix name 'npm run start' 'npm run styles:watch'"
  }
}
```